# Question about HTMLCollections and named properties, continue to use?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, standards, htmlcollection

When referring to elements in HTML forms I often use the name/value of the name attribute. So, if the name of the form is "form01", I refer to the form writing `document.forms.form01`. Here is an example:

```js
let title = document.forms.form01.title;
console.log(title.value);
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <input type="text" name="title" value="Hello World">
</form>
```

The `document.forms` is a HTMLCollection, but in the documentation for the [DOM Standard #interface-htmlcollection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection) it says nothing about the possibility of using a name directly as a property (I think it is called a "named property") on a collection like that -- like when I use `document.forms.form01` to refer to the form element. On the contrary the documentation actually notes that this is "a historical artifact" -- so, should I avoid using it?

Can you help me find documentation for this? Either that it is a (nice) feature that can be used or that it is something that should be avoided.

Comment: I think what you're doing is still standard. Maybe more info [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

Comment: The historical note is about HTMLCollection altogether, not just about the named-properties getter. As a general rule, named-properties access are *bad*™, in this particular case you should be fine, since it's very unlikely that the interface gets extended, but you'd be better using the `namedItem()` method to avoid trouble with an element named `length` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not marked as a deprecated or obsolete feature, you absolutely can continue to use it!

Additional detail on MDN Web Docs about [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) states the following:

> The `HTMLCollection` interface represents a generic collection (array-like object similar to [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)) of elements (in document order) and offers methods and properties for selecting from the list.

---

As for named properties in HTMLCollection (as [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) pointed out), [this section](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dfn-supported-property-names) states:

> The [supported property names](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-supported-property-names) are the values from the list returned by these steps:
>
> 1. Let *result* be an empty list.
> 2. For each *element* [represented by the collection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#represented-by-the-collection), in [tree order](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-order):
>
>    1. If *element* has an [ID](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id) which is not in *result*, append *element*’s [ID](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id) to *result*.
>    2. If *element* is in the [HTML namespace](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#html-namespace) and [has](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element-attribute-has) a [`name` attribute](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-named-attribute) whose [value](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-attribute-value) is neither the empty string nor is in *result*, append *element*’s [`name` attribute](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-named-attribute) [value](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-attribute-value) to *result*.
> 3. Return *result*.

Also note that [NodeList](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) falls under the same section ([Old-style collections](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#old-style-collections)) as HTMLCollection. See [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) on MDN Web Docs.

---

The previous mention of [`[LegacyUnenumerableNamedProperties]`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#LegacyUnenumerableNamedProperties) (as [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) pointed out) only indicates that the named properties are unenumerable (i.e., using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) will only return the index items).

Comment: [LegacyUnenumerableNamedProperties] doesn't on itself indicate that the interface supports named-porperties. [This paragraph](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dfn-supported-property-names) does.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was trying to make sure I attributed correctly and the `supported property names` paragraph didn't catch my eye as easily.